# Getting all files from a certain directory except a certain extension

Tags: c#

I would like to get all the files from a directory except the files that have a certain extension.

In my directory I have the following files:

```
file1.txt
file1.ok
file2.txt
file2.ok
file3.txt
file3.ok 
file4.txt
file5.xml
file6.ok
```

I can get the "ok"-files by using Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.ok")
But how can i get a list of all the other files? A list of all the files that do not have the extions ".ok".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a simple `Where` for this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory)
         .Where(x => Path.GetExtension(x) != ".ok");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Directory.GetFiles("path").Where(x=> Path.GetExtension(x)!=".extension");
```